# The Sum of Two Integral Squares

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

I am looking at the corollary of Fermat theorems from my class note that says:

> Let $p$ be an odd prime number, then $p$ is sum of two integral squares if and only if $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$.

And here is my experiment: Let $p = 5$, then since $5 \equiv 1\pmod 4$, then this equation should have solution:
$$x^2 + y^2 = 5.$$
And indeed the solutions are $1$ and $2$ by simple observation. Let's say that I want to get solutions by working it out instead of by guesswork. Here is what I did using *Gaussian* integers, with some of the steps may turn out to be plain dumb:
$$\begin{align}
x^2 + y^2 &= 5\\
(x + yi)(x - yi) &= 5.
\end{align}$$
Since $5$ is a prime, I foresee only the following factoring:
$$(x+yi) = \pm 1, \pm 5, \pm i \ \ \text{or} \ \pm 5i,$$
with the corresponding factors:
$$(x-yi) = \pm 5, \pm 1, \mp 5i \ \ \text{or} \ \mp i.$$
But whichever combinations I choose, using elimination of system of equations, I never get $1$ and $2$ as the solutions. So here is my question to this forum:

> In which steps did I do the stupid things?

Thanks for your time and help, as always.

Comment: a prime in integer $\mathbb{Z}$ need not be a prime in gaussian integers $\mathbb{Z}[i]$. e.g. $5$ is a prime as integer but factor as $(2+i)(2-i)$ as gaussian integers.

Comment: I think I got my own "Eureka!" moment now. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$5$ is a prime in the integers, but in the Gaussian integers it factors.  Your observation $1^2+2^2=5$ and your factorization in the Gaussian integers should make you think that $(1+2i)(1-2i)=(2+i)(2-i)=5$

Comment: Thank you! So there is no way to working out the solution as I wanted, I meant using only elementary method?

Comment: Scanning the Wikipedia page on [proofs of Fermat's two squares theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proofs_of_Fermat%27s_theorem_on_sums_of_two_squares) I don't see any that give a factorization.  They just prove that one exists.

Comment: @A.Magnus To factor a rational prime $p$ of the form $4k+1$ systematically, one way is first find a solution to the equation $m^2 + 1 \equiv 0 \pmod p$ and then feed it to [Cornacchia's algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cornacchia%27s_algorithm). Look at the wiki entry for details. If we really want to learn this, a good ref is Henri Cohen's book "A course in computational algebraic number theory".

Comment: Thank you, I will take note of this book. Thanks again.